# How to stream audio in GStreamer between 2 python scripts that work on the same computer?

Tags: python, gstreamer, audio-streaming, raspberry-pi4, python-gstreamer

I have 2 pieces of code that works fine up until now. Code A (FileRecord) creates a pipeline and writes whatever it hears from mic to an .ogg file named file.ogg. Code B (FilePlayer) must start after the user stops manual (Ctrl + C) the execution of script A and plays in pulsesink (user's headset) whatever recorder recorded during execution(file.ogg).

My goal is to make the 2 pieces of code work simultaneously and playing file from code B while code A records.

Code A (FileRecord)

```
from time import sleep
import gi
gi.require_version("Gst","1.0")
from gi.repository import Gst
from gi.repository import GLib
import signal


signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, signal.SIG_IGN)       #When Ctrl + Z is pressed file is not playable (this command ignores Ctrl + Z)
print("In order to stop press: Ctrl C.")


Gst.init()
main_loop = GLib.MainLoop()
main_loop_thread = Thread(target = main_loop.run)
main_loop_thread.start()
#buffer = gst_buffer_new ()

pipeline = Gst.parse_launch('autoaudiosrc ! audioconvert ! tee name="source" ! queue ! vorbisenc ! oggmux ! filesink location=file.ogg')

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

try:
    while True:
        sleep(0.1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
main_loop.quit()
main_loop_thread.join()
```

Code B (FilePlayer)

```
from time import sleep
import gi
gi.require_version("Gst","1.0")
from gi.repository import Gst
from gi.repository import GLib
import signal


Gst.init()
main_loop = GLib.MainLoop()
main_loop_thread = Thread(target = main_loop.run)
main_loop_thread.start()

pipeline = Gst.parse_launch('filesrc location=file.ogg ! decodebin ! pulsesink')

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

try:
    while True:
        sleep(0.1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
main_loop.quit()
main_loop_thread.join()
```

I don't know how to achieve sound stream. Please help me!